# Kendo UI + inherit font

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo ui dataviz components (pie and line charts). I need to make the font inherited from the main div.
Is there any attributes to set the font as "inherit" for kendo UI as in css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo UI DataViz uses SVG for charts in newer browsers and VML for old IE (7 and 8). You can use CSS to change the text font, but the VML part wouldn't be affected. Additionally CSS changes are not expected and the label sizing would probably break.

You're better off using the provided configuration options by the Chart to change the font -  [check the documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart) and use "font" filter.